# Print all nodes accessible by at least two paths using DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search

How do we have to modify following DFS algorithm, such that it prints all nodes that are accessible by at least two paths from a starting node s?

```
DFS(G,s):
        foreach v in V do
            color[v] <- white; p[v] <- nil
        DFS-Visit(s)

    DFS-Visit(u)
        color[u] <- grey
        foreach v in Adj[u] do
            if color[v] = white then 
                p[v] = u; DFS-Visit(v)
        color[u] <- black
```

E.g. if the graph is a tree, no node will be printed. If the graph is a cycle, all nodes will be printed.

Comment: This smells like homework... and more liks CS theory, not an actual programming problem.

Comment: Apart from checking for white, also check whether v is black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to write down all the rules we can think of relating to the property we're looking for: that multiple distinct paths exist from s that lead to the node.

1. If u != v both have a path to w, then w is reached by at least two paths.
2. If u has a path to u, then u is reached by at least two paths.
3. if u leads to v, and u is reached by two paths, then v is reached by at least two paths.
4. For every node that is reached by at least two paths, at least one of the three above conditions holds.

We need condition 1 for situations like s->a, s->b, a->c, b->c, c->d, so that c is printed. We need condition 2 for situations like s -> x -> y -> s, so that s is printed. We need condition three so that, for instance, in the above cases, d, x and y are printed. Condition 4 says that these conditions are sufficient.

We can modify DFS by changing our "turn around" condition. Instead of "turning around" when we see a node we've already visited, we simply change state; now instead of looking for unseen nodes, we're doing a DFS from this node for ones that we've seen just once before. During this meta DFS, if we see any we've seen twice before already, we turn back; if we see one we haven't seen before, we mark it as seen more than once and keep going. Once the meta DFS is complete we go back to the original DFS. So nodes have three conditions and we have two states to keep track of. Conditions are:

- Unseen
- Seen once
- Seen more than once

States are:

- Looking for unseen
- Looking for not seen twice

And here's how we handle each of the 6 possible cases:

1. Looking for unseen, find unseen: mark as seen once; remain looking for unseen from current node
2. Looking for unseen, find seen: mark as seen more than once; print node; switch to looking for seen once from current node
3. Looking for unseen, find seen more than once: dead end, end recursion branch
4. Looking for not seen twice, find unseen: mark as seen more than once; print node; continue searching for not seen twice
5. Looking for not seen twice, find seen once: mark as seen more than once; print node; continue searching for not seen twice
6. Looking for not seen twice, find seen more than once: dead end, end recursion branch

Behavior 2 is needed for rules 1 and 2. Behaviors 4 and 5 are needed needed for rule 3. Behaviors 1, 3 and 6 exhaust our other possibilities and ensure that in these cases rule 4 holds.

Comment: Would be great if you could extend your answer with a modified DFS algo in pseudo code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be easily achieved by running BFS instead of DFS, it can also be achieved by running **DFS twice**.

At the **first time**, while visiting a vertex `u` we would like to mark every `v` in `Adj[u]` that is either `gray` or `black`. This means that this vertex has been visited before, meaning it has at least two paths. We will do this by adding another field to the vertices, lets name it `special`.

```
DFS(G,s):
        foreach v in V do
            color[v] <- white; parent[v] <- nil; special[v] <- false
        DFS-Visit(s)

    DFS-Visit(u)
        color[u] <- grey
        foreach v in Adj[u] do
            if color[v] = white then 
                parent[v] = u; DFS-Visit(v)
            if color[v] = gray or color[v] = black
                special[v] <- true
        color[u] <- black
```

Now we know that every vertex `v` that `special[v] == true` can be accessed by at least two paths.
But this is not enough - if you think of a cycle, we will mark only the vertex we started from as `special`. That's why we need another DFS run.

So we want to mark also all the vertices that have a path from a vertex that has already been marked as `special`. We can do this by running **another DFS**:

```
DFS(G,s):
        foreach v in V do
            color[v] <- white; parent[v] <- nil
        DFS-Visit(s)

    DFS-Visit(u)
        color[u] <- grey
        foreach v in Adj[u] do
            if special[u] = true
                special[v] = true
            if color[v] = white then 
                parent[v] = u; DFS-Visit(v)
        color[u] <- black
```

Finally you can print every vertex `v` that has `special[v] == true`.

Comment: Basically every node that is part of a cycle is accessible by at least two paths. So would it not be sufficient to just print out all nodes of a cycle?

Comment: @zabware No, it is not sufficient because you may have cases that a node can be on more then one path but not part of a cycle.

Comment: So now we have two different DFS algos. Can you combine them to one single algo?

Comment: @zabware I don't think you can combine it to one DFS, you might be able to do it in some kind of one run, but the time complexity will remain the same. Personally, I think that this approach is simpler and clear.